Need for causal adjustment formula with shared cause

In a causal model like the one above, when calculating $P(X=x \mid \text{do}(Y=y))$, would we need to use the causal adjustment formula $\sum_c P(X=x \mid Y=y, C=c) P(C=c)$? Once we $\text{do}(Y=y)$, wouldn't the generative process for $Y$ be independent of that of $X$, and therefore $P(X=x \mid \text{do}(Y=y)) = P(X=x)$?

By the displayed causal diagram, only $C$ is the direct cause of $X$, which is  disjoint of $Y$. This permits us to compute $P(X = x \mid \text{do}(Y = y))$ as follows (by Theorem 3.3.2 in Causality by Judea Pearl):
\begin{align*}
P(X = x \mid \text{do}(Y = y)) = \sum_c P(X = x \mid Y = y, C = c)P(C = c).
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
This agrees with the "causal adjustment formula" as you mentioned in the OP.
Furthermore, $\eqref{1}$ can be simplified due to the conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $C$, as dictated by the causal diagram. This can be verified by analyzing all the three paths from $X$ to $Y$:

The path $X \leftarrow C \rightarrow Y$. This path is a fork and the middle  node is $C$ itself.
The path $X \rightarrow B \leftarrow Y$. This path is a collider and the middle node $B$ is not in $\{C\}$ and $B$ has no descendant.
The path $X \leftarrow C \rightarrow B \leftarrow Y$. This path contains a fork $X \leftarrow C \rightarrow B$ where the middle node $C$ is in $\{C\}$, and a collider $C \rightarrow B \leftarrow Y$ where the middle node $B$ is not in $\{C\}$ and $B$ has no descendant.

By the above analysis, the probability $P(X = x \mid Y = y, C = c) = P(X = x \mid C = c)$, whence the right hand side of $\eqref{1}$ reduces to $P(X = x)$.
By the way, your claim "$Y$ be independent of that of $X$" is a false statement, because the middle node $C$ in the fork  $X \leftarrow C \rightarrow Y$ is not in $\{\varnothing\}$. In other words, $P(X = x \mid \text{do}(Y = y)) = P(X = x)$ is the consequence of the conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $C$, rather than the unwarranted unconditional independence of $X$ and $Y$.

The use of conditional independence makes sense, but could you elaborate on how your analysis of the the three paths proves conditional independence?

@Vityou Given a DAG, it is well-known that d-separation is equivalent to conditional independence. The analysis in the answer attempted to show $X$ and $Y$ are d-separated by ${C}$.

@Vityou FYI, a more formal account of my last comment is Theorem 1.2.4 in the same reference of my answer.

Your causal adjustment is needed to block the only remaining confounder $C$ of a backdoor path after the incoming arrow of $Y$ from $C$ has been mutilated during graph surgery which is necessary for the do-calculus applied to a causal graph. And ironically after mutilation $Y$ is apparently independent of $X$ from the DAG, your final equation just becomes $P(X=x \mid \text{do}(Y=y)) = \sum_c P(X=x \mid C=c) P(C=c) = P(X=x)$.
